# result of telprompt:

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there any way to determine when the user comes back to the app from telprompt? If they hit cancel I don't want to do anything but if they hit call when they come back to the app I want to take an action.
Thanks.

Comment: I can't figure out anything to try. I've tried having the uialertview delegate handle the response but there is no way to reference that alertview to assign my view controller as the delegate. Also I thought about handling it in viewdidappear but that doesn't get called on the return. ApplicationdidbecomeActive is called but that seems like a really messy solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSNotificationCenter * center =
    [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

    [center addObserverForName:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                        object:nil
                         queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                    usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note)
    {
        // use instance flag to know
        if (self.isBackfromCalling)
        {
            // do some stuff
        }
    }];
```